# xamarin.ios - Failed to resolve "System.Void ObjCRuntime.BindingImplAttribute

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I recently moved my PCL project into a .NET Standard project, I have upgraded all the packages referenced but when I am trying to build the iOS version I am getting this error -

> Failed to resolve "System.Void ObjCRuntime.BindingImplAttribute::.ctor(ObjCRuntime.BindingImplOptions)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral...."

Xamarin.iOS updated when I connected to my Mac as it said it had a different version of it. Previously it worked perfectly in the PCL Project.

How do I solve this? Or what could be causing this error?

Comment: Are you using the library `LottieXamarin`? If so try to downgrade it to 2.1.5, see [here](https://github.com/martijn00/LottieXamarin/issues/140) for the details issues.

Comment: Yes, thank you it worked!